# AvalonDock: How to use ContentId

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm, avalondock

*(Earlier I had posted a longer version of this question, but a little more brainstorming has revealed that it really boils down to the following simple query):*

Is it mandatory to use `LayoutInitializer` in AvalonDock, or can one live simply by assigning proper `ClientId`s to all `LayoutAnchorable`s in the view and the underlying ViewModels, if I have a static initial layout? Also how does `LayoutSerializationCallback` (of layout serializer) compare with `LayoutInitializer`?